# Memory visibility for the OpenCL host using clEnqueueMapBuffer and 'querying whether the command has finished'

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, opencl

The OpenCL 1.1 standard says (5.2.3):

> If blocking_map is CL_FALSE i.e. map operation is **non-blocking**, the
>   **pointer** to the mapped region **returned by clEnqueueMapBuffer cannot be used until the map command has completed**. The **event** argument
>   returns an event object which **can be used to query the execution
>   status of the map command**. When the map command is completed, the
>   application can access the contents of the mapped region using the
>   pointer returned by clEnqueueMapBuffer.

But in (5.9, immediately after Table 5.15) there is the following statement:

> **Using clGetEventInfo** to determine if a command identified by event has finished execution (i.e. CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS returns
>   CL_COMPLETE) **is not a synchronization point**.  There are **no
>   guarantees that the memory objects being modified by command
>   associated with event will be visible** to other enqueued commands.

---

**Q1**: So, I'm wondering whether there is some other way to "query the execution
status of the map command" and whether memory consistency is quaranteed (for the host in this case) when a query has returned 'CL_COMPLETE'?
**Q2**: Am I missing something?
**Q3**: What are the typical OpenCL idioms for that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- use enqueue barrier and get your event from that commands to have both visibility and fine grained synchronization with host

Waiting it querying in while loop uses more cpu but is fine grained at least

2- events for fine grained control. Waits and barriers for visibility

For example clwaitforevents gives both and uses less cpu but bigger grained than querying

Device side just use event network to have graphs between queues

3-  there isnt any typical. Choose which one suits your problem well

Comment: So, again, it looks like I need another 'machinery' to provide memory visibility guarantees. Hmm, by 'fine grained' you mean  clWaitForEvents imposes more overheads than polling the corresponding event, right?

Comment: Aren't event networks used for having task graphs in an out-of-order queues also? Is support for such queues a widespread option?

Comment: Yes waiting takes longer.  Multiqueue synchronization is fastest with events and out of Order is not a forced option afaik.

Comment: Optional, yes. But it's interesting to know whether implementations of out-of-order queues are available from vendors. From our previous discussion I've made a conclusion that you have an experience with many vendor implementations.

Comment: @parallelgeek I ve tried ooo queue on amd gpu it simply ignored it then I didn't try on intel since amd is already leading opencl. Also nvidia is following from a distance. I don't have nvidia but had some forum people try my programs years ago. Query CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES if it returns a value with ooo_enable. Even if it returns that value, I wouldn't be surprised if it still executes in order. Opencl spec saying only "there is no guarantee that commands are issued in-order" which also implicity says "there is no guarantee its not out-of-order"

Comment: Thank you for sharing that!